# Phong lighting leaves stripes pattern

Tags: c++, shader, opengl-3

I am learning lighting on OpenGL, in this example, I used the [phong method](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting). Everything seems to be working as intended, but I notice that this method leaves some "stripes", especially in the diffuse part of the resulting color:

[image]

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

struct Light{
    vec3 position;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};


uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

uniform Light light;

out vec3 aNormal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 LightPos;

//Usually you would transform the input into coordinates that fall within OpenGL's visible region
void main()
{

    aNormal = mat3(transpose(inverse(View * Model))) * normal; 
    FragPos = vec3(View * Model * vec4(aPos,1.0));
    gl_Position =  Projection  * vec4(FragPos,1.0);
    LightPos = vec3(View * vec4(light.position,1.0));
}
```

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 aNormal;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 LightPos;

struct Material{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light{
    vec3 position;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;
precision highp float;

void main()
{
    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;
    vec3 norm = normalize(aNormal);
    //Difuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(LightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm,lightDir),0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = (diff * material.diffuse) * light.diffuse;

    vec3 specular = vec3(0);
    //Specular
    if(diff > 0){
        vec3 viewDir = normalize(-FragPos);
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir,norm);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir,reflectDir),0.0), material.shininess);
        specular = light.specular * (spec * material.specular);
    }

    vec3 result = diffuse + (ambient + specular);
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
Fragment shader:
```

I was wondering why that happens, I have a suspicion that is related to float precision, however I tried to use `precision highp float;` and it had no effect. What is causing this? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Using a paint tool or similar which gives you hex codes, grab the exact RGB values of the different colors you see. Those might just be the maximum precision that a color can even have on a 24-bit color surface.

Comment: Using Firefox's eyedropper tool easily shows that the lines are adjacent RGB values, where the green intensity is the next higher/lower value (for example, #1f2813 and #1f2913).  You'll need to move to a higher bit color space to improve on what you've got.  (This effect will be less pronounced with red or blue hues.)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- It seems that the color change of each stripe is about 2 bits, and that is enough for the visible color change. Also, the light is at an angle where the dot product doesn't change much for each fragment (hence the small number of stripes)

Comment: If you cannot compel your user to purchase specialized hardware that supports more than 8 bits per channel, consider dithering to smooth the edges when viewed from afar.